# R - Spatial sample from a points layer

Tags: r, shapefile, samplepoints

I read all day several articles regarding various methodologies and tools to create a significant sample from my initial data but I get lost at some point.

It is a shapefile of points.
I would like to select (extract?) a sample, i.e the most representative points, according to their location first, and then according to an attribute (type of point)

I have a population of 330 entities, I know the size of my sample (177).

I browse a lot of packages in R but as I am really a beginner I don't understand how it really works (BalancedSampling, including lcube, sf, sp, SDraw(NPS) not maintained.
I also used QGIS (random selection) but I am not able to understand how this is selected and I need to (try) to understand.

Basically I would like to do something like this example below, in application 2 (but the tools evolved and these ones seem not to be maintained anymore)
[https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318038830_De_nouveaux_packages_pour_selectionner_des_points_d'echantillonnage_spatialement_equilibres_sous_R](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318038830_De_nouveaux_packages_pour_selectionner_des_points_d%27echantillonnage_spatialement_equilibres_sous_R)

The result i would like to get is a spatial sample dataset (an extract from my initial points layer, with the best method cps, gprs, bas) but I get lost.

The examples I saw for BalancedSampling dont show how initial shapefile is used, and its geometry.

Comment: Not sure I understand what it is you are trying to optimise in your sample. Can you define mathematically a quantity that you want to optimise? "representative" of what?

Comment: I believe that the spsurvey package will yield what you are after. Here is the package vignette with good background and examples of various spatial sampling approaches. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spsurvey/vignettes/sampling.html

Comment: Although SDraw isn't on CRAN anymore, I did install it from the last version in the CRAN archive and it seemed to work fine. It may have broken some CRAN technical requirements that don't affect it too much.

Comment: Thank you @Jeffrey Evans: this article solved my problems! i discovered "sp_rbind" which is great function!